# Using liac-arff package instead of arff in python. How to uninstall?

Tags: python

Python has two packages to read arff files. One is [liac-arff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/liac-arff), while the other is [arff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arff/0.9). To use either in a code, the import statement is:

```
import arff
```

I installed both these packages accidently. The way both of them function is different, and I need to use the liac-arff package, but python everytime tries to import the arff one. I tried uninstalling the arff package, but I am stuck. I tried the following but to no success:

```
pip2 uninstall arff
apt-get uninstall python-arff
```

Please suggest to how to uninstall the arff package, or how to make python import liac-arff when the import statement is same?

Comment: How did you install it? From repository or pip?

Comment: And what message do you get when you try `pip2 uninstall arff`?

Comment: When I ran into this error, I was using python 3, and `pip3 uninstall arff`, and it worked perfectly.

I've never seen pip2, only ever pip. Could you try just pip, instead of pip2?